# Trouble finding memory leak (deleting double pointer)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, double-pointer

So I'm writing a program which uses a double pointer in some somewhat deep recursion, and I've got a huge memory leak which I can't find the source of.  The way the program works is (and I'll post some sample code below) that there is a board object with a double pointer called "board" which is the real board (it's a connect 4 game) and another double pointer called "newBoard" which is what is used by a function called minimax() (outside of the Board class).

minimax() is recursive, stepping through each possible route the game could take, and since I don't want to edit the actual board at all, and I figured copying the entire "board" object thousands and thousands of times would be unncecessary, I thought that creating this "newBoard" pointer to copy the actual board would be the best option.

I have a function to delete newBoard, but it's not working like I'd like it to.  Here are the relevant pieces of code:

minimax():

```
void Brain::minimax(Board board, int who, int currentCheck, int iter)
{   
board.createNewBoard();

if (iter <= MAX_ITER)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < w_; i++)
    {
        if (board.playMove(i, currentCheck))
        {
            if (winDetect(board, board.getDisc('c')))
            {
                if (iter == 0)
                {
                    score[i] += 1000;
                }
                else
                    score[i] += (MAX_ITER - iter);
            }


            else if (winDetect(board, board.getDisc('p')))
            {
                if (iter == 1)
                {
                    score[i] += 500;
                }
                else
                    score[i] -= (MAX_ITER - iter);
            }


            else if (!winDetect(board, board.getDisc('c')) && !winDetect(board, board.getDisc('p')))
            {
                if (currentCheck == board.getDisc('p'))
                    currentCheck = board.getDisc('c');
                else if (currentCheck == board.getDisc('c'))
                    currentCheck = board.getDisc('p');

                minimax(board, who, currentCheck, iter + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

createNewBoard():

```
void Board::createNewBoard()
{
newBoard = new int*[h_];
for (int i = 0; i < h_; i++)
    newBoard[i] = new int[w_];
}
```

NB_delete():

```
void Board::NB_delete()
{
for (int i = 0; i < w_; i++)
    delete[] newBoard[i];

delete[] newBoard;
}
```

I think that's all the relevant code, but if you think there might be more, let me know and I'll include it!  Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: SOLVED

I had simply forgotten to call my NB_delete() function. Calling it fixed the program!

Comment: You don't show any place where `NB_delete` is called, and you probably want to `newBoard = nullptr;` to indicate that the memory is no longer allocated (and should cause a crash faster if you use it after deletion!).

Comment: You also probably don't want to wipe out the passed in `Board` parameter. Don't you need that to determine the next steps?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, `newBoard` is a member of class `Board`. Now `minimax` is called recursively and so is `CreateNewBoard`. That means: In `CreateNewBoard` you are overwriting `newBoard` in each successive recursive call! That's probably your memory leak.

If `CreateNewBoard` is to be called recursively, you need a separate instance of `newBoard` for each level of recursion. Or is `newBoard` a 2D array for that very reason and the h_ index denotes recursion depth? In that case you should not create a new instance of `newBoard` in iteration 2 ... h_.

Comment: If I were to get rid of the NB_delete() function and instead include the code from that function (for deleting the current destinations of **newBoard) at the top of the createNewBoard() function, would that work just as well?  I'll try it out